Unable to start spring boot war file from tomcat container
I am using the official tomcat latest docker image. I have created a docker file to use this tomcat image and deploy the war files directly to tomcat webapps. When I run this docker image to start the container the spring boot app is not starting up as I don't see any application startup logs. The same war file when deployed to a local tomcat server is working fine but only when I use sudo to run the catalina.sh run command.
Here is the docker file I used:
##### Use the official Tomcat base image
FROM tomcat:latest

##### Env variable for log path
ENV LOG_PATH=/usr/local/tomcat/logs


##### Copy the WAR file into the webapps directory
COPY service-2.1.6.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

##### Create necessary directories for Tomcat web applications
RUN mv /usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist/* /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

##### Set the environment variable for the active Spring profile
#####ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod

##### Copy the tomcat-users.xml file to configure the manager users
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
COPY context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml

#####Install sudo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo

##### Start Tomcat with sudo
#####CMD ["sudo", "/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]

Tomcat startup logs from docker container:

Tomcat startup logs from local tomcat setup:

What could be wrong or missing here?


The problem was the base tomcat image used for starting the container. My spring boot app was using spring boot version 2.4.5 built using jdk17 version and I was using tomcat:latest image which is using jdk21.
The key here is to have the same version of jdk    used to build the war file and tomcat.
You can check what JDK version the tomcat image uses by checking its layer details and figuring out    the JDK version as shown in the image below. I fixed my problem by    using a tomcat image which supports JDK17 which in my case was    8.5.98-jre17-temurin.
I was also able to run it with 9.0.90-jre17-temurin-jammy as this also used JDK17.



UPDATE
Because your spring boot is 2.4.5
Dockerfile
FROM tomcat:9.0.90-jdk11-temurin-jammy

COPY helloworld.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/helloworld.war

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT []

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

DO NOT USE tomcat:latest

Older Answer
Spring Boot 3.3.x
Dockerfile
FROM tomcat:10.1.25-jdk17-temurin-jammy

COPY service-2.1.6.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/service-2.1.6.war

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT []

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]


(1) Do not install sudo

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo


(2) Do not use sudo to start tomcat, because the internal default of the container is to execute it under the root account.

CMD ["sudo", "/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]


(3) goto "https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat"
(4) find section Supported tags and respective Dockerfile links -> 10.1.25-jdk21-temurin-jammy
(5) click the link 10.1.25-jdk21-temurin-jammy
(6) it will open "https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/3f32851578fdc88622b6dd24c83fef4195249c2d/10.1/jdk21/temurin-jammy/Dockerfile"
(7) Find the bottom of the file.

Line 144 ~ Line 149
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT []

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

(8) Copy the content here to your dockerfile
Build docker image
docker build -t docker-helloworld:0.0.1 .
       
docker tag docker-helloworld:0.0.1 docker-helloworld:latest

Run docker image
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 docker-helloworld


I followed the above steps still issue remains the same. I have updated the question with the Catalina logs which gets printed on startup

@Abhilash - Please check your Host environment, Tomcat Version, JDK version. The difference with the Tomcat version and JDK Version of the Tomcat Container you are using. You are using Spring Boot 2.4.5. Please confirm the JDK version you are using (the difference between Host and Container ). My Spring Boot war uses Spring Boot 3.3.0, JDK 17.

@Abhilash - please Change your Dockerfile, FROM tomcat:latest  -> FROM tomcat:9.0.90-jdk11-temurin-jammy , Spring Boot 2.4.5 + Tomcat 9.0 + JDK 11.

Image tomcat:latest : JDK is 21.0.3 , Tomcat version is 10.1.25. I guess Spring Boot 2.4.5 with Tomcat 10.1 + JDK 21 may not be compatible.

I have spring boot ver 2.4.5 built using jdk17 and my host tomcat version was 8.5.98. Now when I used the same version of tomcat image viz 8.5.98-jre17-temurin the application started working. Not sure what was the issue with earlier versions though

The only information provided at the beginning of the question is: (1) Spring Boot War, (2) Tomcat, (3) tomcat:latest mentioned in Docker. In addition, the version used by Spring Boot and the version used by JDK Version, Host Tomcat and the version used by JDK did not provide a description in the question. Only after I gave the answer and provided a picture, I saw from the picture that the Spring Boot version is 2.4.5. Other than that, the so-called There is no problem with the Local Tomcat version and JDK version, but there is still no relevant information.

In other words, the entire problem description only tells you that Spring Boot 2.4.5 and Image use tomcat:latest, and there is no more detailed information other than that.
